# Overcoming broadcasting error for Legendre polynomails, scipy eval_legendre

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to evaluate the Legendre polynomial P_n(x) with scipy's special function

```
scipy.special.eval_legendre(n, x)
```

which allows you to evaluate a Legendre at certain points. I would then like to sum these Legendre polynomials together, \Sigma_n P_n(x).

Begin by evaluating P_n(x) at several n values, let's say 10. Define an array

```
arr = np.arange(10) = array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

and you can evaluate P_n(x) at these values.

My argument however is a 100 by 100 matrix. So,

```
eval_legendre(np.arange(10), matrix)
```

will not work as there's a broadcasting error. That's easy to overcome.

But then, I would like to take the sum of all of these Legendre polynomials

"Sum = P_0(x) + P_1(x) + P_2(x) + ... + P_10(x)"

using

```
import numpy as np
np.sum()
```

That is more complex, as I am summing each P_n(x).

I suspect the correct approach is something like

```
for i in arr:
    np.sum(i, matrix)
```

Is there a more clean/tidy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
sum( [eval_legendre(x,matrix) for x in range(1,10)] )
```

Each call to the `eval_legendre` function returns a matrix of the shape of the matrix you pass to it. So we can make a list of these matrices using list comprehension, and sum them as you suggested.

Comment: There's no need for the for loop, just use broadcasting and np.newindex as usual.

Comment: @ pv. :I'm not sure I follow you. This is a Legendre polynomial P_n(x) with n values (10,) and the argument a matrix (100,100).

Comment: @StackG: I appreciate the help. My only other question is why does "Sum" maintain my matrix shape (i.e. array (100,100)) but np.sum returns a float?

Comment: I think this is just an implementation issue - sum() applies the addition operator to everything in a list - we have a list of matrices, and by default matrices add by point-wise addition. In comparison, np.sum() sums along or down one axis - documentation is here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

Comment: @pv. What do you mean? I'm still having trouble using broadcasting to avoid the for loop. This is a Legendre polynomial P_n(x) with n values (10,) and the argument a matrix (100,100). So, I want to sum the (matrix evaluated at n=0) plus (matrix evaluated at n=1) plus (matrix evaluated at n=2) and etc. Broadcasting gets confusing at this point for me.

Comment: @pv. :At the moment, using `np.sum( [eval_legendre(arr, matrix)` where `arr = np.arange(10)` gives me an error. 
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (100,100)`
How can I overcome this using broadcasting?